# Web Service(.asmx) is throwing 404 error in IIS 7

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis

I am facing one issue related to Web Service call. It is running very well in my local machine. but once i deploy it on the web(IIS 7)Server and trying to make the service call, at that moment it is throwing 404(resource not found)error.

For your kind Information, I have kept the service on proper location on the web server, i have also checked the permission it is also ok. 
For your hint, the jsdebug is not getting created on the web Server
for example:
if i am putting the url in my local machine http://localhost:8080/Service.asmx/jsdebug then jsdebug is coming with download option but when i am putting the same on web server then following error is coming:

"404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Please Suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem got resolved. we were updating our application with **DNN 7.3** when we encountered this problem. The solution in this scenerio was to remove the *Routing protocols* from webconfig which was provided by **DNN**.

Thanks a lot for reply I appriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

JS

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'WebService.asmx/YourMethod',
        data: {},
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) { 
              alert(result.d);
        },
        failure: function (error) {
        }
    });
```

ASMX

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[Serializable]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

            [WebMethod]
            public string YourMethod()
            {
                  return "OK";
            }
}
```

WebConfig (inside system.web tag)

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```